# Joining 3 tables without row count got increased

Tags: mysql

I need to join three tables in certain way and I have no idea how to formulate my query better. There are my three tables:

```
ROOM table:
-----------
ID    NAME
1   "Kinosál 1"
2   "Kinosál 2"
3   "Kinosál 3"
4   "Kinosál 4"


SEAT table:
-----------
ID      NAME       RESERVED  ROOM_ID
1   "Seat 1 Room 1"    1      1
2   "Seat 2 Room 1"    0      1
3   "Seat 3 Room 1"    0      1
4   "Seat 4 Room 1"    0      1
5   "Seat 1 Room 2"    1      2
6   "Seat 2 Room 2"    0      2
7   "Seat 3 Room 2"    0      2
8   "Seat 4 Room 2"    0      2
9   "Seat 1 Room 3"    1      3
10  "Seat 2 Room 3"    0      3
11  "Seat 3 Room 3"    0      3
12  "Seat 4 Room 3"    0      3
13  "Seat 1 Room 4"    1      4
14  "Seat 2 Room 4"    0      4
15  "Seat 3 Room 4"    0      4
16  "Seat 4 Room 4"    0      4


FILM table:
----------
ID    TITLE         DESCRIPTION      ROOM_ID
1     "Title1"    "Description1"        1
2     "Title1"    "Description1"        1
3     "Title1"    "Description1"        1
4     "Title1"    "Description1"        1
5     "Title2"    "Description2"        2
6     "Title2"    "Description2"        2
7     "Title2"    "Description2"        2
8     "Title2"    "Description2"        2
9     "Title3"    "Description3"        3
10    "Title3"    "Description3"        3
11    "Title3"    "Description3"        3
12    "Title3"    "Description3"        3
13    "Title4"    "Description4"        4
14    "Title4"    "Description4"        4
15    "Title4"    "Description4"        4
16    "Title4"    "Description4"        4
```

This is the result which I would like to get (without empty columns). I only want to put this three tables next to each other:
[image]

I tried to use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbName.room r

JOIN dbName.seat s
ON r.id = s.room_id

JOIN dbName.film f
ON r.id = f.room_id
```

I was sure this query is good. The first Join gives me exactly what I want but when I add the second join, it gives me different result with almost 4 times more rows then i expect. I have no idea why and mainly I have no idea how to fix it. Please, does anybody see where I make some obvious mistake and how to improve my query?

My wrong result:
[image]

Comment: Your `film` table looks wrong. Why does it have same data 4 times ? For eg: `ID = 1,2,3,4` - all of them have same data

Comment: 'but when I add another join,'.... What exactly are you adding? I do not see any other table in this question, and no description on how you are adding this extra table

Comment: Luuk: I meant the second join. Room => join Seat => join Film

Comment: The content of your `film` table is invalid. You have multiple rows with the same ID value, which means that if you have 5 rows with ID = 5, then the **proper** result is 5 rows with ID = 5. You need to fix your data before your query will function as it should. The old expression *Garbage In, Garbage Out* applies here - your data is garbage (invalid), so your results will be garbage (invalid) as well.

Comment: The question has been updated with correct input data and it behaves identically as before. Please, try to help me one more time.

Comment: @user8620575 although your data still seems wrong, but since you mentioned that you are getting duplicated row. Try `SELECT DISTINCT * ....`

Comment: Well, it does not return duplicated rows but for some reason it makes something like Cross join (more combinations than i want). Disctinct does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Though I must say, You have a really bad DB design or might be possible you have only used wrong sample data here to show us. Still, You would always get 4 times data as you have multiple matches against each ID by using `r.id = f.room_id`. You should try below query -

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbName.room r
JOIN dbName.seat s ON r.id = s.room_id
JOIN dbName.film f ON s.id = f.id
```

While talking about your DB design, Presuming one room can have only 1 film, You can go with the below DB design -

```
ROOM table:
-----------
ID    NAME
1   "Kinosál 1"
2   "Kinosál 2"
3   "Kinosál 3"
4   "Kinosál 4"

FILM table:
----------
ID    TITLE       DESCRIPTION           ROOM_ID
1     "Title1"    "Description1"        1
2     "Title2"    "Description2"        2
3     "Title3"    "Description3"        3
4     "Title4"    "Description4"        4

SEAT table:
-----------
ID  NAME        RESERVED  ROOM_ID
1   "Seat 1"    1         1
2   "Seat 2"    0         1
3   "Seat 3"    0         1
4   "Seat 4"    0         1
5   "Seat 1"    1         2
6   "Seat 2"    0         2
7   "Seat 3"    0         2
8   "Seat 4"    0         2
9   "Seat 1"    1         3
10  "Seat 2"    0         3
11  "Seat 3"    0         3
12  "Seat 4"    0         3
13  "Seat 1"    1         4
14  "Seat 2"    0         4
15  "Seat 3"    0         4
16  "Seat 4"    0         4
```

With the above DB design, You can try your own query -

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbName.room r
JOIN dbName.film f ON r.id = f.room_id
JOIN dbName.seat s ON r.id = s.room_id
```

Comment: Oh, yes!! This totally works!! There is one big problem - there is no relationship between tables seat and film (and their id's) :-( So I would not defend it in my boss. For that reason i guess i should not add film_id as a foreign key to seat table either.  Could you please give me an advice about better tables design to resolve it?